# How do I add a command to the tab context menu in Sublime?

Tags: plugins, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I would like to add a command from my plugin to this context menu:

[image]

This is the menu that pops up when you right click on a file. I only know how to add a command to the context menu that pops up when you right click on the background; I can't find the documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is to create a file called "Tab Context.sublime-menu" in the plugin folder** and add a menu item to it.

For example, the default options displayed in the graphic in the question are displayed as follows:

> ```
> [
>   { "command": "close_by_index", "args": { "group": -1, "index": -1 }, "caption": "Close" },
>   { "command": "close_others_by_index", "args": { "group": -1, "index": -1 }, "caption": "Close Other Tabs" },
>   { "command": "close_to_right_by_index", "args": { "group": -1, "index": -1 }, "caption": "Close Tabs to the Right" },
>   { "caption": "-" },
>   { "command": "new_file", "caption": "New File" },
>   { "command": "prompt_open_file", "caption": "Open File" }
> ]
> ```

*Tab Context.sublime-menu* is located in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\<plugin>\` in this example.